# Using Jackson2 in JBoss AS 7.1 - ModuleNotFoundException

Tags: java, jboss, jackson

I'm trying to use Jackson2 annotations in the web project I'm studying ([Goncalves petstore-ee6](https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-application-petstore-ee6)).
I need to deploy the dependency resteasy-jackson2-provider as a module and exclude JBoss's default provided version (Jackson 1.9).

I followed [this recommendations](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html/json.html#d4e1044) in order to achieve that but I can't make it work.

In the project's pom.xml, I added :

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
 <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In the WEB-INF dir I created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml containing this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
 <deployment>
  <exclusions>
   <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
  </exclusions>
  <dependencies>
   <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import" />
  </dependencies>
 </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The dependencies are included into the WAR-file/WEB-INF/lib but I get the following exception when trying to deploy :

```
14:23:56,165 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.applicationPetstore.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.applicationPetstore.war".main: Failed to load module: deployment.applicationPetstore.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider:main is not found in local module loader @e902fd (roots: D:\dev\ide\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadExportedModule(ModuleLoader.java:233)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:246)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ServiceModuleLoader.preloadModule(ServiceModuleLoader.java:160) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:841)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1181)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1207)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:208)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

I looked several posts about deploying a project with dependencies that are already provided by JBoss but didn't find something that worked for me...

What am I missing or understanding wrong ?
What should I do in order to use Jackson2 with JBoss ?
If possible, I'd like to avoid the use of static modules since I'm not supposed to have access rights to JBOSS_HOME.
Additional info : I'm using JBoss 7.1.1 Final.
I hope that is meaningful, English is not my native language.

Comment: You want to deploy new OSGi module (jackson2) to Jboss instead of using existing one and don't want to change standalone.xml file?

Comment: I'm not really sure about OSGI (need to document about it), I just want to deploy a web application which depends on Jackson2 which would be provided in the WAR-file. I understood that I need to bypass the Jackson version provided by JBoss and give my own. It resembles the case of using a [custom log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136035/how-to-enable-a-custom-log4j-with-jboss-as-7-1).
If possible, I don't want to modify JBoss installation because I'm not supposed to have administrative rights onto.

Comment: I think you can just remove file jboss-deployment-structure.xml (or jackson related part) from your war file. JBoss should use jakson2 from WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I tried but it shows the same result :(.

Answer (score 0):

Did it work for you?

I did add the org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider module into JBOSS_HOME and server starts fine.

I do use below dependency in my code.

```
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2.Final</version>
```

Still when I make a call it is using the codehaus jackson.

```
1:18:35,227 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8016-1)     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
11:18:35,227 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8016-1)    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
11:18:35,227 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8016-1)    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
11:18:35,227 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8016-1)    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
11:18:35,227 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8016-1)    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
11:18:35,227 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8016-1)    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580
```

Comment: No, after lots of trials I never managed to use Jackson 2 with JBoss AS 7.1, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is right, but you also need to install the module you are using in your JBoss.

JBoss modules are loaded from modules folder, it does not matter if it is included on your project dependencies or in your war.